# What is the specification of this Perl array type?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have found this array definition in one Perl script:

```
 my $in_field = {};
 $in_field->{NAME}        = "John";
 $in_field->{SURNAME}     = "Black";
 $in_field->{PHONE}       = "01234";
```

What type of array is it? I am not so skillful in Perl and I tried to find it in Google, but it is difficult to find it without any meaningful keyword. I tried to look for the definition "= {}" and for the operator "->", for the arrays in global, but I didn't succeed.

Is there some specification of it?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$in_field` is a scalar.

`$in_field` contains a reference to a hash.

Hashes are documented in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and references in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: NB: There is no array here at all. The aforementioned *perldata* explains the differences between arrays and hashes.